# Find first negative number and prepend a zero

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to insert a `0` before the first occurrence of `-` followed by a number.

I have tried the below simple code.

```
$formula = '[ (((-594 - 0) )/ 55032411) *244 ]';
preg_match('/^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$/', $formula, $match);

print_r($match);
$result = str_replace($match[0],'0'.$match[0],$formula);
echo $result;
exit;
```

I want the below result.

```
[ (((0-594 - 0) )/ 55032411) *244 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

No capture group is needed if you use a lookahead for a single digit. This is a pretty fast pattern.

Pattern: `-(?=\d)`

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1RJTC8/2)

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/80b62571bd8be12e8dc0d75dbcb39db4fd9a7ae9))

```
$formula='[ (((-594 - 0) )/ 55032411) *244 ]';
var_export(preg_replace('/-(?=\d)/','0-',$formula,1)); // match -, prepend 0
```

Output:

```
'[ (((0-594 - 0) )/ 55032411) *244 ]'
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `preg_replace` function:

```
$formula = '[ (((-594 - 0) )/ 55032411) *244 ]';
$result = preg_replace('/-?\d+(\.\d+)?/', '0$0', $formula, 1);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
[ (((0-594 - 0) )/ 55032411) *244 ]
```

---

The 4th argument `1` passed to `preg_replace` is the maximum replacements for the pattern in the input string

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm a firm believer that Regex != 42 I made a non regex that may work.
In short, it finds the first `-` in the string and saves the position.
Anything before this - is $part, but I use str_replace to remove all `[() and space`.
Then if this part is empty then there is no number before the first `-` so add the 0.

It's a bit complex but since it does not use regex it may be faster. But if you use other signs than `[() and space` in the start of calculation you need to add them in the arrays to remove.
Now that I think about it maybe `+-/*` should be there.

```
 $formula = '[ (((-594 - 0) )/ 55032411) *244 ]';
 $pos = strpos($formula, "-");
 $part = str_replace(array("(",")","["," "), array("","","",""),substr($formula, 0, $pos));

If($part ==""){
     $formula = substr($formula, 0,$pos) ."0". substr($formula, $pos);
 }

Echo $formula;
```

I admit that it is complex, but I wanted to try to make a non regex solution.
https://3v4l.org/TaSjr

Comment: You can make `str_replace()`'s second parameter an empty string instead of a 4-element array.

Comment: @mickmackusa didn't know that. I thought if you had an array on find you need an array on replace

Comment: If all of the replacements are the same, you can condense them this way.  What does  your Regex!=42 mean?

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=42 "42 - The Almighty Answer to the Meaning of Life, the Universe, and Everything"